# Can not sign in with google in angular

Tags: angularjs

i am trying angular for the first time. i am trying to sign in with google account. But It is not working. When i load the page the button appears and then after loading it hides. and the code is not working to. 
here is my app.html

```
<body >
      <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
      <button ng-click="update()">Post data</button>    
      </div>


       <div ng-controller="SignCtrl">
<span id="signinButton" >
   <span class="g-signin" ng-click="signIn()"></span>
</span>
  <button onclick="SignedOut();">SignedOut</button>
       </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="appMy1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="GSignIn.js">  </script> 
</body>
```

Here is my controller

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.factory("GPlusAuthService", function ($q, $window) {
    var signIn;
    signIn = function () {
        var defered = $q.defer();
        $window.signinCallback = function (response) {
            $window.signinCallback = undefined;
            defered.resolve(response);
        };

        gapi.auth.signIn({
            clientid: "389760997134-uredjv5rat0k3vsjaqlt7nn4pbgtqrat.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            cookiepolicy: "single_host_origin",
            requestvisibleactions: "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
            scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read",
            callback: "signinCallback"

        }) 
        return defered.promise;
    };
    return {
        signIn: signIn
    }


});

app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope,$http) {

$scope.update=function(){

    $http.post("/user/signup",{Name:'Mr.x',Email:'AX@gmail.com',Organisation:'Ruet',PlacesLived:'dhaka',Img_url:'xyz'})
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(headers);
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     //console.log(data);
    console.log(headers);     
  });
}
}),
app.controller('SignCtrl', function ($scope, GPlusAuthService) {
    $scope.signIn = function() {
        GPlusAuthService.signIn().then(function(response) {

        });    
    }
});
```

Any clue what i am doing wrong?
The error is "cookiepolicy is a required field". But i have mentioned the cookiepolicy.